# PHP strip letters and put values into array

Tags: php

I have these two pieces of text

```
120 - 140 (cm)
```

and

```
 110 (cm)
```

I'd like to store the values into an array like

```
$array[0] = 120
$array[1] = 140

$array_2[0] = 110
```

How would i do this?

Comment: Do you have the 2 texts in variables ?

Comment: I'd go with regex if you're absolutely sure that every time the format will be exactly as you described it above.

Comment: Yes the text are in variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
function numArray($str)
{
    $str = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", " ", $str);
    return preg_split('/ /', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

$str = "120 - 140 (cm)";

$array = numArray($str);
```

That will return an array with only numbers in it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array_2 = array();

$array[0] = 120;
$array[1] = 140;

$array_2[0] = 110;
?>
```

Comment: Here you have to tell me the difference to OP's code

Comment: @Lenap OP wants to parse piece of text...